# Shorten Pure Function

Tags: pure-function

My task is to write a pure function with 5 characters or less that can be called with a single number a or a list {a,b,c} and returns 1/a^3 or {1/a^3,1/b^3, 1/c^3,...}, depending on the input. I am new to Mathematica and a unsure about the potential of pure functions. So far, I came up with the following code which yields the desired output, though at too many characters:

```
#^-3&[x]
```

Does someone see a way to shorten this to <= 5 characters and is the code above in accordance with the idea of pure functions?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Consider `function = #^-3 &`

Comment: thank you! have updated the question

Comment: can you write `f[#] &` ? this is 5 characters. screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs383.png)  (do not know if this agrees with the rules you have or not)

Comment: good one, honestly i don't know, the assignment question is kind of ambiguous in that regard.. thank you!

Comment: @noob3000 Can you explain what further enhancement you seek? `#^-3&` is already five characters long, and it can be applied to single arguments as well as lists thanks to the fact that `Power` is already `Listable` so it should fit your requirements, no?

Comment: you are right, thank you for your kind help!

Comment: To add to what @MarcoB said: programming shouldn't be a contest of using the fewest possible characters.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit totally agree! tell my lecturer haha..